# Subcontext menu is not displayed correctly in Windows 7 but in Windows 10 yes, why?

Tags: windows-registry, context-menu, regedit

Windows 10: displayed correctly

[WavPack on Windows 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WVvk.png)

Windows 7: not displayed correctly

[WavPack on Windows 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekIR9.png)

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.wav\shell\WavPack]
"Icon"="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\wavpack-5.1.0-x86\\WavPack.ico\""
"MultiSelectModel"="Single"
"Subcommands"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.wav\shell\WavPack\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.wav\shell\WavPack\shell\Hybrid]
"Icon"="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\wavpack-5.1.0-x86\\WavPack.ico\""
"MultiSelectModel"="Single"
"Subcommands"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.wav\shell\WavPack\shell\Hybrid\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.wav\shell\WavPack\shell\Hybrid\shell\1) Compress this file]
@="Compress this file"
"Icon"="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\wavpack-5.1.0-x86\\WavPack.ico\""
"MultiSelectModel"="Single"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.wav\shell\WavPack\shell\Hybrid\shell\1) Compress this file\command]
@="WScript \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\wavpack-5.1.0-x86\\Compress.vbs\" \"%1\" Hybrid"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.wav\shell\WavPack\shell\Hybrid\shell\2) Compress all .wav]
@="Compress all .wav"
"Icon"="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\wavpack-5.1.0-x86\\WavPack.ico\""
"MultiSelectModel"="Single"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.wav\shell\WavPack\shell\Hybrid\shell\2) Compress all .wav\command]
@="WScript \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\wavpack-5.1.0-x86\\Compress.vbs\" *.wav Hybrid"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.wav\shell\WavPack\shell\Hybrid\shell\3) Compress all files]
@="Compress all files"
"Icon"="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\wavpack-5.1.0-x86\\WavPack.ico\""
"MultiSelectModel"="Single"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.wav\shell\WavPack\shell\Hybrid\shell\3) Compress all files\command]
@="WScript \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\wavpack-5.1.0-x86\\Compress.vbs\" * Hybrid"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.wav\shell\WavPack\shell\Lossless]
"Icon"="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\wavpack-5.1.0-x86\\WavPack.ico\""
"MultiSelectModel"="Single"
"Subcommands"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.wav\shell\WavPack\shell\Lossless\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.wav\shell\WavPack\shell\Lossless\shell\1) Compress this file]
@="Compress this file"
"Icon"="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\wavpack-5.1.0-x86\\WavPack.ico\""
"MultiSelectModel"="Single"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.wav\shell\WavPack\shell\Lossless\shell\1) Compress this file\command]
@="WScript \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\wavpack-5.1.0-x86\\Compress.vbs\" \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.wav\shell\WavPack\shell\Lossless\shell\2) Compress all .wav]
@="Compress all .wav"
"Icon"="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\wavpack-5.1.0-x86\\WavPack.ico\""
"MultiSelectModel"="Single"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.wav\shell\WavPack\shell\Lossless\shell\2) Compress all .wav\command]
@="WScript \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\wavpack-5.1.0-x86\\Compress.vbs\" *.wav"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.wav\shell\WavPack\shell\Lossless\shell\3) Compress all files]
@="Compress all files"
"Icon"="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\wavpack-5.1.0-x86\\WavPack.ico\""
"MultiSelectModel"="Single"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.wav\shell\WavPack\shell\Lossless\shell\3) Compress all files\command]
@="WScript \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\wavpack-5.1.0-x86\\Compress.vbs\" *"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm solved it with this: "MUIVerb"

From:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.wav\shell\WavPack\shell\Lossless]
"Icon"="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\wavpack-5.1.0-x86\\WavPack.ico\""
"MultiSelectModel"="Single"
"Subcommands"=""
```

To:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.wav\shell\WavPack\shell\Lossless]
"Icon"="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\wavpack-5.1.0-x86\\WavPack.ico\""
"MUIVerb"="Lossless"
"MultiSelectModel"="Single"
"Subcommands"=""
```